# Pandas series to row of dataframe using loc but some columns are missing

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a series to a row of a dataframe but not every column is in the dataframe. How can I change the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2], columns = ['A', 'B'])
series = pd.Series(data=[5,3], index=['B', 'C'])

df.loc[0] = series
print(df)

Output:
     A    B
0  NaN    5
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
```

such that it automatically adds missing columns to the dataframe and I get this

```
Output:
     A    B    C
0  NaN    5    3
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

So far I tried this but got an keyError:

```
df.loc[0, series.index] = series

Output:
KeyError: "['C'] not in index"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but you can do it in a for loop:

```
for c in series.index:
    df.loc[0, c] = series[c]

df
     A    B    C
0  NaN    5  3.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Another way is to add null columns to df before assigning to series:

```
df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist() + [c for c in series.index if c not in df.columns])
df.loc[0, series.index] = series

df
     A    B    C
0  NaN    5  3.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: you can also try index.union for such usecases: `df.reindex(df.columns.union(series.index,sort=False),axis=1)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your series to DataFrame and use `combine_first` or `combine`:

```
df.combine_first(series.to_frame(name=0).T) # to fill the second row set 'name' to 1
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  5.0  3.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
```